# copy text to clipboard in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Todo :**

- I want to make something like this in Ionic 
  [image]
- I have tried using 2 button, 1 active button and another disable event button but no luck in ionic.

> Is there any textbox I can use to make some thing like that and how to?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? Implementing the copy to clipboard feature or designing something similar to your screenshot ? To use copy to clipboard feature, you can use this plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/clipboard/

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm install @capacitor/clipboard
npx cap sync
```

Example:

```js
import { Clipboard } from '@capacitor/clipboard';

const writeToClipboard = async () => {
  await Clipboard.write({
    string: "Hello World!"
  });
};

const checkClipboard = async () => {
  const { type, value } = await Clipboard.read();

  console.log(`Got ${type} from clipboard: ${value}`);
};
```

Source and more details: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/clipboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As I have struggled with this same problem recently and neither the official documentation or most StackOverflow answers have helped, I wanted to leave this here since the solution that I found, while maybe not answering exactly what the author of the post needed, might help someone. Note that this example is based on **Ionic-Angular** and might not be useful for Ionic-React or Ionic-Vue implementations.

Oddly enough, in **Android** at least, the paste from the clipboard can be detected by the (ionInput) event. Therefore, even if the text was pasted from an external app (WhatsApp, browser, etc) you can use something like this to read the pasted text in your device's clipboard:

HTML:

```
<ion-input formControlName="myInput" (ionInput)="onInput($event)"></ion-input>
```

TS:

```
import { Clipboard, ReadResult } from '@capacitor/clipboard';

  onInput(event) {
    Clipboard.read().then((clipboardRead: ReadResult) => {
      if (clipboardRead?.value) {
      // Call any functions, method, do whatever you need with the input
      // call event.preventDefault() if you need to do anything with the captured string instead of pasting it directly into the input
      event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    });
}
```

Another approach is to place the Clipboard.read() function in the constructor, but since the read() method returns a Promise I have found that it will only work once per component or page initialization, and thus I wasn't able to detect the copied string after the first successful capture. Or to put it in another way, I was able to capture a string from the clipboard once, but not a second time on the same page. Placing the function inside the ionViewWillEnter cycle didn't do the trick either if I put another app or browser in the foreground to copy a piece of text and try to paste it a second time, so I discarded that approach.

On **iOS**, at least from what I could test on an iPhoneX and a 2nd generation iPhone SE (I might edit this answer after testing more modern models), the paste from the clipboard can be captured through the (paste) event, so it doesn't seem like there is a need for a specific iOS implementation. It would look like this:

HTML:

```
<ion-input formControlName="myInput" (paste)="onPaste($event)"></ion-input>
```

TS:

```
    onPaste(event) {
    // console.log('full event > onPaste', event)
    event.preventDefault();
    const pastedData = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    // Do whatever you need with the pasted string
  }
```