# Ionic 4 monitoring clipboard changes

Tags: ionic4, system, overlay, clipboard

I am a new in ionic 4. I have an use case to develop a mobile application. I prefer to do with hybrid (ionic 4).

As you know if user do copy text action from any application, OS use the clipboard and keep the copy text on memory. Any application can read that text from Clipboard."

My use case is I want to create an application which is always on top (like system overlay) and monitoring the clipboard changes. If there is value on the clipboard, I want to do something and give some suggestion to user.

Kindly suggest me a system design with sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Capacitor has an [api](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/clipboard/) to the clipboard. This example is from the docs:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Clipboard } = Plugins;

Clipboard.write({
  string: "Hello, Moto"
});

let str = await Clipboard.read({
  type: "string"
});
console.log('Got string from clipboard:', str.value);
```

The api also has listeners to the clipboard. It should support your use case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

(The answer below is pasted from my original reply here [copy text to clipboard in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058961/copy-text-to-clipboard-in-ionic/77912282#77912282) , on a similar thread)

As I have struggled with this same problem recently and neither the official documentation or most StackOverflow answers have helped, I wanted to leave this here since the solution that I found, while maybe not answering exactly what the author of the post needed, might help someone. Note that this example is based on **Ionic-Angular** and might not be useful for Ionic-React or Ionic-Vue implementations.

Oddly enough, in **Android** at least, the paste from the clipboard can be detected by the (ionInput) event. Therefore, even if the text was pasted from an external app (WhatsApp, browser, etc) you can use something like this to read the pasted text in your device's clipboard:

HTML:

```
<ion-input formControlName="myInput" (ionInput)="onInput($event)"></ion-input>
```

TS:

```
import { Clipboard, ReadResult } from '@capacitor/clipboard';

  onInput(event) {
    Clipboard.read().then((clipboardRead: ReadResult) => {
      if (clipboardRead?.value) {
      // Call any functions, method, do whatever you need with the input
      // call event.preventDefault() if you need to do anything with the captured string instead of pasting it directly into the input
      event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    });
}
```

Another approach is to place the Clipboard.read() function in the constructor, but since the read() method returns a Promise I have found that it will only work once per component or page initialization, and thus I wasn't able to detect the copied string after the first successful capture. Or to put it in another way, I was able to capture a string from the clipboard once, but not a second time on the same page. Placing the function inside the ionViewWillEnter cycle didn't do the trick either if I put another app or browser in the foreground to copy a piece of text and try to paste it a second time, so I discarded that approach.

On iOS, at least from what I could test on an iPhoneX and an iPhone SE 2nd generation (I might edit this answer after testing more modern models), the paste from the clipboard can be captured through the (paste) event, so it doesn't seem like there is a need for a specific iOS implementation. It would look like this:

HTML:

<ion-input formControlName="myInput" (paste)="onPaste($event)">

TS:

```
    onPaste(event) {
    // console.log('full event > onPaste', event)
    event.preventDefault();
    const pastedData = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    // Do whatever you need with the pasted string
  }
```